# SFDC Apex Code: Access class level static variable from "Future" method

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I need to do a callout to webservice from my ApexController class. To do this, I have an asycn method with attribute @future (callout=true). The webservice call needs to refeence an object that gets populated in save call from VF page.

Since, static (future) calls does not all objects to be passed in as method argument, I was planning to add the data in a static Map and access that in my static method to do a webservice call out. However, the static Map object is getting re-initalized and is null in the static method.

I will really appreciate if anyone can give me some pointeres on how to address this issue. 
Thanks!

Here is the code snipped:

```
      private static Map<String, WidgetModels.LeadInformation> leadsMap;

       ....
       ......
        public PageReference save() {

       if(leadsMap == null){
           leadsMap = new Map<String, WidgetModels.LeadInformation>();
        }
        leadsMap.put(guid,widgetLead);

       }
        //make async call to Widegt Webservice
        saveWidgetCallInformation(guid)

       //async call to widge webserivce  
      @future (callout=true)
      public static void saveWidgetCallInformation(String guid) {
        WidgetModels.LeadInformation cachedLeadInfo =   
        (WidgetModels.LeadInformation)leadsMap.get(guid);
      .....
      //call websevice

      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`@future`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm) is totally separate execution context. It won't have access to any history of how it was called (meaning all static variables are reset, you start with fresh governor limits etc. Like a new action initiated by the user).

The only thing it will "know" is the method parameters that were passed to it. And you can't pass whole objects, you need to pass primitives (Integer, String, DateTime etc) or collections of primitives (List, Set, Map).

If you can access all the info you need from the database - just pass a `List<Id>` for example and query it.

If you can't - you can cheat by serializing your objects and passing them as `List<String>`. Check the documentation around JSON class or these 2 handy posts:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/passing-objects-to-future-annotated-methods.html
- https://gist.github.com/kevinohara80/1790817

---

Side note - can you rethink your flow? If the starting point is Visualforce you can skip the @future step. Do the callout first and then the DML (if needed). That way the usual "you have uncommitted work pending" error won't be triggered. This thing is there not only to annoy developers ;) It's there to make you rethink your design. You're asking the application to have open transaction & lock on the table(s) for up to 2 minutes. And you're giving yourself extra work - will you rollback your changes correctly when the insert went OK but callout failed?

By reversing the order of operations (callout first, then the DML) you're making it simpler - there was no save attempt to DB so there's nothing to roll back if the save fails.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, I need the Saleforce lead id to pass to my web service so had to DML first and then need to do a call out. I will appreciate if you have any other suggestion. I just tried the serialization approach and passing object data as JSON string and that should to the trick.  Thanks agian for your suggestion.

Comment: Which database is considered "master" - SF or this ext. system? You might be able to work around it by first calling out, having that system return the lead id it generated on it's side ("ABC000123") and then inserting the lead. Then that system can refer to these leads by the 'external id' field on the lead (should be unique for best results), it wouldn't need the real SF Id to send updates or insert related data for example.

Comment: Hi, so master system is SF. We have a custom VF page (opened via CTI popup) where rep gathers lead information from caller. On page submitted, the SF lead object is created and saved. The SF Lead Id, along with some custom info (not being stored in SF but captured from VF page) need to be send to our external system. Unfortunately, we can not create a custom table in SFDC to store this additional data or modify standard Lead Object because of business constraints (requirements).  Thanks again for your suggestions and feedback. Really appreciate it!!

Comment: Hmm, then I think it has to stay the way you've designed. You'd have to reverse the flow, say display the other app as iframe / connected app (do you use chatter?), save that "Lead+more" there and have it silently post back to SF... Doesn't sound like it's worth the effort, the page wouldn't match SF styling, you lose SF translations (if you use the workbench that is) + CTI might mean extra challenges with cross-domain JavaScript for example... And if it has data not stored on the object it means "outbound message" from workflow won't work either. Sorry, really looks like it needs @future then

Comment: Thanks so much validating the design. First time doing this so was not sure of the approach :-). Seems to be working. Also, like the fact that expensive web service call is done async so it will not impact user experience on SF side.

Comment: I was trying to access the instance variable(public variable with class level scope - correct me if I am wrong) set in another class, but no value was being set when I used it. "Do not have any access to History" was the answer for me! I was also able to see in the debug logs as well that the class is initialized again with variables set fresh. Thanks a lot :)